# Using temporary table in Stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written *stored procedure* and it takes long time when i call it. 
I use temporary table in 'SP'.
it can be reason ??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MYTEMP_table (A, B )
      (  SELECT  id AS CUSTOMER_NO,
              ACC_NO AS ACCOUNT_NO
           FROM  myTable );
UPDATE MYTEMP_table
      SET MYTEMP_table.A =
             (  SELECT MIN (BRH_DATE)
                  FROM CUSTOMER,)



   UPDATE MYTEMP_table
      SET MYTEMP_table.B =
             (  SELECT MIN (SUBSTR (ENTRY_DATE, 0, 8))
                  FROM INFO)
                .......
```

MYTEMP_table is temporary table.

Comment: Yes it can, and then it may be something completely different. This is impossible to answer with that little information. Flip a coin.

Comment: What can i use instead of temp table ?? how can i resolve it without using temp table

Comment: It's unlikely that the major performance impact is caused by the use of temporary table. It's usually poorly written code.

Comment: have you run an explain plan to see what is going on? You don't specify what "a long time" is.  How many data rows are getting accessed, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet looks woefully incomplete.  Seems odd that you are filling the temp table with one query:

```
select id, acc_no from myTable
```

and then wiping out all columns with a single value:

```
UPDATE MYTEMP_table
SET MYTEMP_table.A =
       (  SELECT MIN (BRH_DATE)
            FROM CUSTOMER,)
```

Your post is not clear, but *hopefully* you are using a global temporary table (Memory based) rather than a physical table meant for temporary storage.

Multiple writes to the same rows is a sure-fire way of slowing down the works (Much more-so in a physical table, but still slow either way).  If possible, consider the following:

1. Use analytic functions or a more complex initial query to get all your writing done up front...
2. If you're not comfortable/familiar with running/reading explain plans, try running each SQL statement in a SQL Editor manually to assess their individual performance...